# Resizing virtual hard disk on VMWare

Tags: vmware

We're unable to resize our SCSI virtual hard disk on VMWare. We have 200GB of extra space for resizing, but the "Provisioned Size" field under "Disk Provisioning" is grayed out.

Here's a checklist of measures we've already taken:

1. We've shut down the VM
2. We've deleted all snapshots
3. Made sure the hard disk is SCSI

Any ideas on why we can't resize the virtual hard disk?

Comment: What platform please?

Comment: It's running on Red Hat Linux

Comment: I meant what VMware platform? Player? VSphere? Workstation?

Comment: did you thin provision it?